# Is it possible add html code using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to detect if a "gap class" exists will add html code:

Convert

```
<html>
<script>
    $('#gap').find('.gap');
    if "gap"
    <li><span class="gap">...</span></li>
    end
<script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li> 
  <li>2</li> 
  <span class="gap">...</span>
  <li>4</li> 
</ul>
```

Result

```
<li><span class="gap">...</span></li>
```

Comment: Appending to the html, writing to document, etc. Also, I hope that's not real code

Comment: @Andrew L you would be surprised...

Comment: Yes, that's not a real code is just and example if somebody knows how to deal with this.

Comment: @JacobFrye I just did...

Comment: @Azamantes I've see much worse. I've also grown to not become surprised when seeing people's 'code'

Comment: Very obvious you have done absolutely no research on this. Not to mention html result is invalid

Comment: Note that a LI element **has** to be a child of an OL/UL element, and a SPAN can't be a direct child of an UL element, so the question makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry about that but didn't know how to search the exactly word. i never did that in my life.

Comment: Yes of course it comes from an UL TAG , i want to detect "GAP CLASS" and add only that.

Comment: If the SPAN is a direct child of an UL, the browser will move it out of the UL as it's invalid HTML, hence it can't be found where you think it is.

Comment: I edited the information, so $('.gap').wrap('<li></li>') will work?

Comment: Well, no, that code won't work with the given HTML, because it's still **invalid**, you can't have a span in an UL

Comment: @JacobFrye no....invalid html will cause unknown displacements depending on browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: Yes you can use [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)
by default the `$('.gap')` selector it look for `.gap` class in your HTML, if it found it, it wrap it into `li` element.

demo:

```js
$('.gap').wrap('<li></li>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="gap">...</span>
```

**Note**

dont use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) result will be

```
<span class="gap">...<li></li></span>
```

**Edit:**

anyway `<span class="gap">...<li></li></span>` or `<li><span class="gap">...</span></li>` both of them are not a valid HTML `li` elements should be inside `ul` element
please check these link, to undertand more about both of them append and wrap

Comment: This makes no sense either. If the `<li>` doesn't exist then the span can't be set as child of `<ul>` in browser since it's invalid. Browser will throw it out

Comment: I edited the code.

Comment: @charlietfl edited :) , thanks for note :=

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could append element to another using `append()` in jquery :

```
$('.gap').append('<li><span class="gap">...</span></li>');
```

Or using `appendChild()` for vanilla javascript or also using `innerHTML` :

```
Element.innerHTML += 'Content to append';
```

But in your case you have to replace the `.gap` element by `li`, so you could use `replaceWith()` method :

```
$('.gap').replaceWith('<li><span class="gap">...</span></li>');
```

**NOTE :** your `.gap` element should be replace by `li` for the valid html because `span` should not be appended to `ul`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean $('.gap').append('<<li>span class="gap">...</span></li>');

Comment: Come on...has to be valid html. Can't append `<li>` to `<span>`

Comment: I edited the code.

Comment: @JacobFrye Need to fix the source so it is valid html regardless of what anyone is answering here

Comment: `replaceWith` assumes that browser will leave the invalid tag in place. That is not how browsers deal with invalid markup. will have different results in different browsers but generally they get kicked out of invalid parent

Comment: And you have tested it across all browsers? Bet you didn't try IE